# Can Makefile string functions be nested?

Tags: string, function, makefile, nested

I'm attempting to do some string manipulation in a Makefile using the [string functions](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_8.html) that Make offers. I want to do two conversions on my strings, I have a variable that lists source files similar to:

```
C_SRCS += \
./src/foo.c \
./src/bar.c \
...
```

I want to take this string and convert it in a new variable holding all the object files. The Objects will be stored in a different directory, and obvious will have a `.o` extension instead of the `.c`. Effectively they should change from:

```
./src/<file>.c
```

to

```
./artifacts/src/<file>.o
```

I can do this with two rules like:

```
OBJS1 := $(C_SRCS:%.c=%.o)
OBJS = $(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(OBJS1))
```

that will work fine, but I was hoping to combine these two rules and remove the intermediate variable. I tried:

```
OBJS = $($(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS)):%.c=%.o)
```

and that just left `OBJS` empty, I thought maybe it would be better if I used two of the exact same function type so I tried:

```
OBJS = $(subst %.c,%.o,$(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS)))
```

and that executed the nested rule only and `OBJS` was set to `./artifacts/src/foo.c ./artifacts/src/bar.c ...`

I started reading through some Make documentation, but I can't find anything about nesting string functions. Is it possible to nest string functions in Makefiles? If so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can nest string functions.

You cannot use the shorthand `:X=Y` notation on the result of a function though.

So when you combined `OBJS1 := $(C_SRCS:%.c=%.o)` and `OBJS = $(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(OBJS1))` you didn't do that correctly (or the obvious way) you did something else. You wrote `OBJS = $($(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS)):%.c=%.o)` when the obvious (and correct) nesting would have been `OBJS = $(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS:%.c=%.o))`. (Maybe that was a typo I'm not sure).

The `:X=Y` shorthand is a shorthand for `patsubst` (an automatically `%` prefixed shorthand) not `subst` which is why your line `OBJS = $(subst %.c,%.o,$(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS)))` didn't work (consider otherwise that `$(C_SRCS:.c=.o)` would happen in more places than just the end of the values).

See below for working versions.

```
C_SRCS += \
          ./src/foo.c \
          ./src/bar.c

pv = $(warning $1: $($1))
$(call pv,C_SRCS)

$(warning RAW: $(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS:%.c=%.o)))

OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS)))
$(call pv,OBJS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the wrong way around.  Just "expand the macro" and replace `$(OBJS1)` in `$(OBJS)`:

```
OBJS1 := $(C_SRCS:%.c=%.o)
OBJS = $(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(OBJS1))
```

becomes:

```
OBJS = $(subst ./,./artifacts/,$(C_SRCS:%.c=%.o))
```